# Symbol fill color in lattice using auto.key

Tags: r, lattice

I'm making a plot using `xyplot` in `lattice` (R 15.2, lattice 0.20-13) in which I have several groups that I would like to distinguish by the shape of the marker. I need to use a downward facing triangle which is only available as a hollow symbol (`pch=25`) unlike up triangle which is available as a filled (`pch=17`) or hollow (`pch=24`) symbol. I can specify both the outline color and the fill color for these symbols in `par.settings(superpose.line())`, but when I plot an `auto.key`, there is no fill. Is there some way to get the `auto.key` to be consistent with the plot symbols?

This is an example of what I'm describing:

```
data <- data.frame(x_var = rep(1:10, 2), y_var = rnorm(20), group=rep(c(1,2),each=10))

xyplot(y_var ~ x_var, groups=group, data=data,
       par.settings=list(superpose.symbol=list(col=c("red", "blue"), fill=c("red", "blue"), pch=c(24, 25), cex=2)),
       auto.key=list(space="right"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried both your version and the version [available at CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/) today (0.20-14). Both of them fail to fill the symbols of the legend. However, your code works correctly with version [0.20-10](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lattice/lattice_0.20-10.tar.gz). Therefore, I am afraid you have found a bug. Could you send an email to the maintainer?

UPDATE: This bug has been fixed in version 0.20-15.

Comment: Nice find.  I have lattice_0.20-6 and it works correctly with that version as well.

Comment: And after upgrading to lattice_0.20-13 it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
par.settings = list(strip.background=list(col="red"), superpose.symbol = list (  pch = c(17,19,22), col=c("red", "green", "blue" )))